# nextjs react state not update when function parse to child component

Tags: reactjs, canvas, next.js, react-hooks, frontend

```
    "use client";

import { EntityType, World } from "@/types/World";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
;

let RayTracingPage = dynamic(()=>import("./RayTracingCanvas"));
let initialMovements = [0,0,0,0,0]
export default async function Home() {
    const [world, setWorld] = useState<World>({
    
        lights: [
            {
                x: -30,
                y: -10,
                z: 20,
            },
        ],

        camera: {
            point: {
                x: 0,
                y: 1.8,
                z: 10,
            },
            fov: 45,
            direction: {
                x: 0,
                y: 3,
                z: 0,
            },
        },

        entities: [
            {
                type: EntityType.Sphere,
                point: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 3.5,
                    z: -3,
                },
                color: { // 0=> purple
                    r: 155,
                    g: 50,
                    b: 155,
                    a: 255
                },
                specular: 0.2,
                lambert: 0.7,
                ambient: 0.1,          p0:0,

                radius: 1,
                speed: 0.1
            },
            {
                type: EntityType.Sphere,
                point: {
                    x: -4,
                    y: 3.5,
                    z: -1,
                },
                color: { // 1 => red
                    r: 155,
                    g: 25,
                    b: 40,
                    a:255
                },
                specular: 0.1,
                lambert: 0.9,
                ambient: 0.0,
                radius: 0.2,          p0:0,

                speed: 0.2
            },
            {
                type: EntityType.Sphere,
                point: { // 2 => green
                    x: -7,
                    y: 3.5,
                    z: -10,
                },
                color: {
                    r: 34,
                    g: 255,
                    b: 34,
                    a: 255
                },
                specular: 0.2,
                lambert: 0.7,
                ambient: 0.1,
                radius: 0.1,          p0:0,

                speed: 0.3
            },
            {
            type: EntityType.Sphere,
            point: {
                x: -8,
                y: 3.5,
                z: -5,
            },
            color: { // 3 => dark blue
                r: 34,
                g: 13,
                b: 134,
                a: 255
            },
            specular: 0.2,
            lambert: 0.7,
            ambient: 0.1,
            radius: 0.3,          p0:0,

            speed: 0.4
            },
            {
            type: EntityType.Sphere,
            point: {
                x: -14,
                y: 3.5,
                z: -3,
            },
            color: { // 4 => yellow
                r: 230,
                g: 230,
                b: 21,
                a: 255
            },
            specular: 0.2,
            lambert: 0.7,
            ambient: 0.1,
            radius: 0.5,
            p0:0,
            speed: 0.5
        },
        ]
    });
    const [movements,setMovements] = useState<number[]>(initialMovements)
    const motionUpdate:()=> World =()=>{
        let newMovements:number[]=[]
        for(let i = 0; i < movements.length; i++){
            newMovements.push(movements[i] + world.entities[i].speed)
        }
        console.log(movements)

        setMovements(newMovements);
        world.entities[0].point.x = Math.sin(movements[0]);
        world.entities[0].point.z = Math.cos(movements[0]);
    
        world.entities[1].point.x = Math.sin(movements[1]) * 2;
        world.entities[1].point.z = -4 + Math.cos(movements[1]) * 2;
    
        world.entities[2].point.x = Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
        world.entities[2].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[2]) * 3;
        world.entities[2].point.y = 3.5 + Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
    
        world.entities[3].point.x = Math.sin(movements[3]) * 2;
        world.entities[3].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[3]) * 2;
    
        world.entities[4].point.x = Math.sin(movements[4]) * 4;
        world.entities[4].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
        world.entities[4].point.y = 3.5 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
        return world
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <CanvasPage width={1280} height={720} AnimationCallback={motionUpdate}></CanvasPage>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my react state not updated every time, movements is set back to default values, any idea why is this happening

```
const motionUpdate:()=> World =useCallback(()=>{
        setWorld(world=>{
            const newWorld = { ...world };

            setMovements((moves)=>{
                let newMovements:number[]=[]

                for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
                    newMovements.push(moves[i] + world.entities[i].speed)
                }
                return newMovements
            });
            newWorld.entities[0].point.x = Math.sin(movements[0]);
            newWorld.entities[0].point.z = Math.cos(movements[0]);
        
            newWorld.entities[1].point.x = Math.sin(movements[1]) * 2;
            newWorld.entities[1].point.z = -4 + Math.cos(movements[1]) * 2;
        
            newWorld.entities[2].point.x = Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
            newWorld.entities[2].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[2]) * 3;
            newWorld.entities[2].point.y = 3.5 + Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
        
            newWorld.entities[3].point.x = Math.sin(movements[3]) * 2;
            newWorld.entities[3].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[3]) * 2;
        
            newWorld.entities[4].point.x = Math.sin(movements[4]) * 4;
            newWorld.entities[4].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
            newWorld.entities[4].point.y = 3.5 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
            return newWorld
        })
        return world
        
    },[movements, world])
```

Try update my code with above function and canvas still not updated
I assume it is because too many calls to motionUpdate function prevent state to be updated, maybe I need use reduce function, what is the best solution for this?

Comment: movements not updated immediately

Answer (score 0):

Please properly format your code, as there is a lonesome semicolon in there. Furhermore you are directly mutating the `world` state rather than calling `setWorld`.

In your function you could do something like the following:

```
// ...

setWorld((previous) => {
  const newWorld = { ...previous };
  
  newWorld.entities[0].point.x = Math.sin(movements[0]);
  newWorld.entities[0].point.z = Math.cos(movements[0]);
    
  newWorld.entities[1].point.x = Math.sin(movements[1]) * 2;
  newWorld.entities[1].point.z = -4 + Math.cos(movements[1]) * 2;
    
  newWorld.entities[2].point.x = Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
  newWorld.entities[2].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[2]) * 3;
  newWorld.entities[2].point.y = 3.5 + Math.sin(movements[2]) * 3;
    
  newWorld.entities[3].point.x = Math.sin(movements[3]) * 2;
  newWorld.entities[3].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[3]) * 2;
    
  newWorld.entities[4].point.x = Math.sin(movements[4]) * 4;
  newWorld.entities[4].point.z = -3 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
  newWorld.entities[4].point.y = 3.5 + Math.cos(movements[4]) * 4;
  
  return newWorld;
});
```

Also consider wrapping your function inside a `useCallback` since it will be recreated on each render otherwise.

##### Please note

There is no need to repeatedly slam the same sentence over and over again.

Comment: just updated post

Comment: You have a set state inside a set state. That will be the problem.